# get mysql table columns description

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get my table's columns ***description***
I tried `fetch_fields()` but it doesn't fetch the description (just name, type, length ...)

```
  $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();
                foreach ($finfo as $val) {
                    if (in_array($val->name, $columns['names'])){
                        $ths .= '<th scope="col" id="'.$val->name.'">'.$val->name. '</th>';
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch `COLUMN_COMMENT` from [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/columns-table.html).